# r caret package: is there anyway to pass trainset into summary function?

Tags: r

I've been trying to define summary function for specific purpose.
The problem is I need some variables from train data in order to compute specific metric.
I've been looking into source code of train.default as well as defaultSummary function and evalSummaryFunction. So I realized that trainset has to pass to evalSummaryFunction. However, I couldn't able to pass the trainset in it. Is there anyway to do this?